# How to search sub string in NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a question describd below:

I have UITextView showing following content:

> Maybe it's because he doesn't settle.
>   ***[Give funny anecdote about something the groom did not settle
>   for. It should not be related to
>   dating or marriage.]*** Or maybe it's
>   something else. I can't put my finger
>   on it, but I just never saw him
>   settling down.
>
> Well, one day that all changed.
>   ***[Tell story about how the groom met the bride and what he told you after
>   they met.]*** Yes, meeting ***[bride's
>   name]*** changed everything.
>
> ***[Groom's name]*** stopped sounding picky and started sounding interested.
>   He knew that what he had in this woman
>   was amazing―like nothing he had ever
>   experienced before. After mere weeks,
>   he was deeply in love; and there was
>   no way out.
>
> And you know what? He never turned
>   back. And here he is today with his
>   beautiful bride. Could there be a more
>   perfect match?
>
> So let that be a lesson to all of you
>   loveless old maids here tonight. No
>   matter how bad you think your
>   situation is, it can't be as bad as
>   ***[groom's name]***'s; and he ended up with what he wanted most.
>
> And with that, I will close.
>   ***[Groom's name]*** and [bride's name], you two are both amazing
>   people. Alone, you can accomplish
>   great things. Alone, you are funny,
>   intelligent, charming people.

Now have a look on the strings written between "[]", (square brackets). Initially, this text will in non editable format. I have a button on the top of the screen named as "Edit". Now what I have to do, When I click on the "Edit" button, there should pop ups showing text fields and when I enter data in the text fields then that text will replace the strings written between the "[]". For example, in above text there is a string "[Groom's name]" so when I Tap on the edit button then there will be pop up asking me "Enter the name of Groom", When I enter the name of groom in the text field then that name will replace the "[Groom's name]" with the text written by me in the textfield. For each strings written between the "[]" there should be a popup. Now my question is how I will track these square brackets and after that how will I replace them with the text entered by me in text field.

If I m clear then u will understand that in the above text I have to replace all the strings in bold italic format.

If I am not clear on any point please let me know. Thanks in advance

Comment: Those last two sentences look a bit dodgy:  "alone you are funny etc" i.e. not together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [NSString](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) you can do that (combining -rangeOfString and – stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:)

But don't hesitate to use [RegexKitLite](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/RegexKitLite/), then you'll have access to the power of regular expressions

---

Some clues to do that with NSString :

1. search [ and get it position
2. search ] and get it position
3. get the string in this range
4. replace characters in this range with the string you prompted

Comment: Santoni: Thanks for your answer I did the same as u said and its working awesome. Thanks once again :-)

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to avail yourself of one of the many [Cocoa RegEx](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?RegularExpressions) libraries that exist.

Answer (score 0):

You're in luck.  In iOS 4, we have the NSRegularExpression class.